# R: Change COLUMN NAMES from scientific notation to decimal

Tags: r, types, scientific-notation

I have columns that denote intervals and some of these entries are in scientific notation and seemingly out of order. It looks like this:

```
(500,500] (1.4e+04,1.45e+03] (750,800] (600,650] (1.2e+03,1.25e+03]
column     column           column     column    column
```

Ideally, I want all my column names in decimal notation, i.e.:

```
(500,500] (1400,1450] (750,800] (600,650] (1200,1250]
column     column     column     column    column
```

I have added the columns by using:

```
    df <- df %>% mutate(ind = cut(mean_entry, breaks = c(-Inf, c(0, seq(100, 2000,by = 50 )))), 
col_name = ind, n = 1) %>%pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = n, values_fill= list(n = 0))
```

Does anyone know how I can do that? I'd like to avoid hard-coding every applicable column name but please let me know if that's the only way forward. I don't have package preferences and appreciate any insight.

Thanks!

Comment: `options(scipen = 99)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Where exactly do I run this command?

Comment: Run in the R console once.

Comment: Thanks! But that didn't solve my problem. The column names haven't changed. Do you know of another approach?

Comment: Share a reproducible example on which we can test our answers and provide suggestions.

Comment: I've added how I made built the intervals! Please check it out.

Comment: @RonakShah Maybe the fact that the colum names start and end with brackets have something to do with the notation not changing?

Comment: Actually your code is still not reproducible. We don't have `df` before or after casting data into wide. You can use `dput(df)` to share your data. If the data is big use `dput(head(df, 10))` to share first few rows.

Comment: I think I know why options(scipen = 99) is not working. I'm not trying to change the column entries but only the column name and it seems that scipen doesn't affect column names but only entries. Is there a way to avoid hard-coding column names?